# Utility function, plotting indifference curves

Tags: graphing-functions, economics, utility

I know how to plot indifference curves; simply take the utility function and plot some level curves in $2D$.

But how to plot a specific indifference curve, so all bundles on it are indifferent to a specific $(a,b)$ bundle?

Would I calculate the utility for $(a,b)$, then set $U(x,y)$ equal to that utility, then plot that level curve?

Answer (score 1):

```
Would I calculate the utility for (a,b) , then set U(x,y)

 equal to that utility, then plot that level curve?
```

This is a good idea.

Suppose $U(x,y)=x^{1/2}\cdot y^{1/2}$ and $(a,b)=(36,100)$. Thus $U(36,100)=6 \cdot 10=60$

$60=x^{1/2}\cdot y^{1/2} \Rightarrow y=\frac{3600}{x}$